# Irregular grid lines on one part of css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've got a really simple grid set up in CSS, but when I look at the grid lines in the inspector there's a strange irregularity at the bottom. I can't understand why this exists when the rest of the grid lines are all regular.

There's no special styling on div-4, it's just the same as the rest. Is it something to do with the margins produced by the h3 tag?

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="left-sidebar-grid">
    <div class="div1">
        <h3>Div1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <h3>Div2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
        <h3>Div3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="div4">
        <h3>Div4</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.left-sidebar-grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 16px;
}

.div1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
.div2 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2; }
.div3 { grid-area: 4 / 1 / 10 / 2; }
.div4 { grid-area: 10 / 1 / 11 / 2; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined only 8 explicit rows and you have placed the `div4` starting at line 10 which will create 2 extra rows so you will end up with 10 rows in total where only 8 are sized using the `1fr` and 2 will have an `auto` size: the empty one you see and the one where you placed div4.

To avoid this use `grid-auto-rows:1fr` instead of your template in order to make sure all the rows are sized the same way:

```css
.left-sidebar-grid {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 16px;
}

.div1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
.div2 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2; }
.div3 { grid-area: 4 / 1 / 10 / 2; }
.div4 { grid-area: 10 / 1 / 11 / 2; }
```

```html
<div class="left-sidebar-grid">
    <div class="div1">
        <h3>Div1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <h3>Div2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
        <h3>Div3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="div4">
        <h3>Div4</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

You can also simplify your code like below:

```css
.left-sidebar-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 16px;
}

.div1 {
  grid-row:span 1;
}

.div2 {
  grid-row:span 2;
}

.div3 {
  grid-row:span 6;
}

.div4 {
  grid-row:span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-sidebar-grid">
  <div class="div1">
    <h3>Div1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <h3>Div2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    <h3>Div3</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="div4">
    <h3>Div4</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I realised what I was doing wrong about 20 seconds after posting. But I never knew grid-auto-rows was a thing, so thank you!

Comment: @user9754798 don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue